# Angular Dart Material Daterange picker height

Tags: dart, angular-material2, angular-dart

I use **`<material-date-range-picker ...>`** but it is displayed to tall. I found that `material_date_range_picker.scss` declares `.main-content { ...; height: $datepicker-main-content-height; ... }` and $datepicker-main-content-height is defined as $mat-grid * 9 which is 72px. The component looks ugly and breaks a layout. Other datepicker components don't define height and look normal.
I tried to override the height in my CSS by `:host .main-content { height: auto !important}` but as Angular adds some _ngcontent-rnp-XX classes to elements it doesn't apply.
Does anybody know how to style **material-date-range-picker** height? (And why it is styled to have fixed height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you might want to try to use this mixin here which might work better for your environment. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/c644746d2824df7cfaf0a34f900b1f8557caddbc/angular_components/lib/material_datepicker/_mixins.scss#L221

You can also see how it sets the .main-content height by using :ng-deep. For Google products we don't want people to customize using ng-deep as it makes everything part of public API which makes migrations hard, but it should be OK in this content.

We are going to look into providing a mixin for teams to set the height themselves in a more maintenance friendly manner.

I'm glad you like using the widgets, but I would ask that you take care with your criticism. This particular design works well for our products and many of our designers love it and thinks it looks beautiful. I understand it doesn't work for your use case, but hopefully the customization outlined above will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Ted. Using mixin looks good, I'll try it. Sorry for the misunderstanding, by saying that the component looks ugly I just wanted to point out it looks differently and uses different definition than other date picker components. Which make it hard to use these together. But definitely Angular Dart and material components as a whole are great and that's why I use it.